# Specflow need to save the TestExecution.json file when project is using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, specflow, .net-framework-version, temporary-files

**Background:**

I'm attempting to consume the `TestExecution.json` file with the living documentation command line tool from SpecFlow

when I build and run tests using the `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>` the `TestExecution.Json` file saves to a random temp folder in my particular case

-> LivingDocPlugin: Output generated in: `C:\Users\c338129\AppData\Local\Temp\c169af79-5ce8-43f8-b0b8-06adab8fbcec\c169af79-5ce8-43f8-b0b8-06adab8fbcec\assembly\dl3\ddf95881\f22f4f2c_8ef4d801\TestExecution.json`

But by the time I looked there just a few seconds later it's already gone.

however if I change the target framework to `<TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>` it works correctly

-> LivingDocPlugin: Output generated in: `C:\Users\c338129\source\repos\Cvs.SpecFlowExample\Cvs.SpecFlowExample\bin\Debug\net5\TestExecution.json`

It behaves correctly and place the text execution with the rest of the outputs from build.

Currently we are not able to upgrade this project off of framework *(YET)* so in the meantime is there anything I can do to cause the framework build and test to create the TestExecution.json in the same way that it does for net 5 or net 6

**Project file for version references**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.9.74" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5"/>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Drivers\" />
    <Folder Include="Support\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Troubleshooting So far:**

consulted the troubleshooting doc [living Docs TroubleShooting](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Guides/Troubleshooting.html)

**Question:**

What can I do get the TestExecution.json be created in with the rest of the build artifacts when running as a .NET Framework 4.x project?